# JsonSerializable and JsonKey issue after upgrade on Flutter Freezed model

Tags: flutter, freezed, json-serializable, json-annotation

My app was running ok but after pub upgrade --major-versions I am getting problems on all models.
Example model:

```
import 'package:app_220/models/Leads/LeadFieldModel.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

part 'LeadModel.freezed.dart';
part 'LeadModel.g.dart';

@freezed
abstract class LeadModel with _$LeadModel {
  const LeadModel._();

  @JsonSerializable(fieldRename: FieldRename.snake)
  const factory LeadModel({
    required int id,
    int? formId,
    @JsonKey(name: 'contact__first_name', defaultValue: '')
    @Default('')
        String contactFirstName,
    @JsonKey(name: 'contact__last_name', defaultValue: '')
    @Default('')
        String contactLastName,
    @JsonKey(name: 'contact__email', defaultValue: '')
    @Default('')
        String contactEmail,
    @JsonKey(name: 'contact__phone', defaultValue: '')
    @Default('')
        String contactPhone,
    int? staffId,
    @Default('') String staffLastName,
    DateTime? creationTime,
    @Default('') String sourceUrl,
    @Default('') String sourceIp,
    @Default(0) int viewed,
    List<LeadFieldModel>? leadData,
  }) = _LeadModel;

  factory LeadModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$LeadModelFromJson(json);
}
```

Problems:

```
The annotation 'JsonSerializable' can only be used on classes
The annotation 'JsonKey' can only be used on fields or getters
...
```

In order to make it work on the previous upgrade a few weeks ago, I set a fixed version for json_annotation: '4.0.1' and json_serializable: '4.1.4' in the pubspec.yaml, but I wonder if there is another way to update those packages without any issue.

What am I missing, how can I achieve the same effect as before using freezed?

Comment: Any updates here ? I still see in latest freezed documentation that the same approach is recommended

Answer (score 9):

The author is aware of this limitation [as indicated here](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed/issues/488).  Personally I disagree with the solution of "just disable the warning" as it silences legitimate warnings, and this is almost never a valid engineering solution.  An alternative proposed therein indicates adding the following comment above any usage where you are certain that the warning is not problematic:

> // ignore: invalid_annotation_target

This isn't great either for large codebases, but it places the responsibility on you to decide what to ignore while also allowing you to receive valid warnings elsewhere.